# what happens with data declared as const in c++

Tags: c++

When we declare the `const` variable it is said in Bruce eckel book that constant folding happens that means memory is not allocated for the variable.

What happens when we declare the variable as `const`?

1. How is the compiler free to optimise `const` variables?
2. Is memory for `const` variables is always allocated, and under which circumstances it may not be?

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you want to know.

Comment: I wanted what is memory folding and why memory folding  is done for const variable .

Comment: Looks like "memory folding" is a term Eckel invented (if the OP is quoting correctly) - a google for it reveals nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following quote on a PDF attributed to Bruce Eckel:

> const int bufsize = 100; You can use
>   bufsize anyplace where the compiler
>   must know the value at compile time.
>   The compiler can use bufsize to
>   perform constant folding, which means
>   the compiler will reduce a complicated
>   constant expression to a simple one by
>   performing the necessary calculations
>   at compile time. This is especially
>   important in array definitions:

Assuming that you meant "constant folding" and not "memory folding", what he means is the following:

```
const int i = 10;
const int j = 20;
int k = i + j;
```

Memory does not have to be allocated for `i` and `j` if the compiler can prove that this is the only time they are used.  In that case, it can replace all three lines with `int k = 30;`  Because the variables were marked `const`, the compiler is free to assume their values never change, and it is smart enough to do the addition for you in advance rather than wait for run-time.

For what its worth, I would not worry about this too much if you're still learning the language.  Its an implementation detail; you can generally count on it happening, but the end result is the same either way.  Write code that makes sense, use `const` as needed to prevent mistakes [*not* as a means to save memory], and if the compiler is able to spit out something special for you then all the better.

----------- Original answer follows, since it is a sort of related topic

Without a direct quote, my guess is he is referring to something like this:

```
//in file 1:
const char* string1 = "Hello world!";
//in file 2:
const char* string2 = "Hello world!";
//in file 3:
const char* string3 = "world!";
```

Under some circumstances, the compiler/linker is able to spot that `string1` and `string2` both point to the same string.  So it does not have to create two separate string objects that contain the same data, and `assert(string1 == string2)` would end up succeeding.  An even more intelligent setup could notice that `string3` is a substring of the first two, and you end up with `assert(string3 == string1+6)`.  In the executable's actual data, you end up with one string, even though in the code there are three of them.

In C++, it doesn't really matter that they are `const`, because you can't assign a non-const `char*` to a string literal.  But in general, that substitution would not be valid if any of the three strings were allowed to modify the memory they point to.  The user probably doesn't intend for `*string1 = '5'` to change `*string2`, so the three strings can not be condensed in that case.

Comment: Correct dennis its constant folding as you said "Memory does not have to be allocated for i and j if " then where the value will be stored.Do you think these value are stored in the symbol table.since each compilation unit possess a symbol table.I am not sure though

Comment: @Chris: They would get entries in the symbol table while compiling, yes, just marked as constants.  After compilation, in a case like this they likely just vanish, with the value `50` appearing directly inside the instructions.  Other times, a new value will be inserted along with any other data the executable has stored away.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is free to optimise const variables (and anything else) as long as you can't tell the difference from what the program does.

For example:

```
const int three = 3;
const int four = 4;

int f() { return three * four; }
```

Here the compiler is free to omit allocating storage for the variables, and will probably produce exactly the same code as if it was written `return 12;`

But if you took the address of `three`, or bound a reference to it, or declared it as extern, then the compiler would probably be forced to allocate memory for it.

Comment: I agree with you Alan but where the value for three and four gets stored .Do you mean they are stored in symbol table?

Comment: They might not be stored in the binary if they're not needed at runtime - for example, if they're marked file static and only used in expressions like the one above. Even if they're needed at runtime, they might be stored directly in the processor instructions, and not in a .DATA section.

Comment: The compiler needs to know the values, so yes, they'd have to be accessed via the symbol table somehow. At runtime there's no need to store the values.

Comment: @gnud there's no need to make them explicitly static, const variables have internal linkage by default.

Answer (score 0):

> " means memory is not allocated for the variable .. "

You are mistaken. If it is a variable( be it either const or non const), it should reside in some part of memory.

When you declare a variable as `const` means, the variable cannot be modified in it's life time.

```
const int num = 10 ;

num = 20 ; // Error : num cannot be modified. It is just a read only variable.

int var = 10 ;
var = 20 ;  // var is a modifiable integer variable.
```

Comment: For function scope, or file static const variables, the compiler knows when compiling a CU whether the address of the variable is ever taken, or just its value used. If it's address is never taken then it could replace uses of the const variable with the variable value; at least for simple types.

Comment: @Simone, you can only safely const cast something that wasn't really const to start with. The compiler is free to place const variables in read-only memory.

Comment: @Simone: That causes undefined behavior tho.

Comment: An incomplete answer, there's const member functions and the subtleties of pointers and const. Then there's const_cast and the mutable keyword. And what does 'const volatile' mean?

Comment: @Skizz- Well, the OP mentioned about `const` variables. I was just trying to give an idea.

Comment: @Autopulated and @Itjax, nonetheless the keyword exists and should be mentioned. IMHO

Comment: @Simone: The question is specifically about a variable declared as `const`. In that specific case, you CANNOT use `const_cast`. It's only legal to use `const_cast` to remove a `const` that's been added _after_ the declaration of the variable. E.g. `int a = 5; int const* pa = &a; const_cast<int&>(*pa); // OK, not originally const`